# Compilation of postgresql-8.4.7 for Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, visual-studio-2005, compilation

Because of several dependencies in the libraries my company uses internally, I have to compile postgresql-8.4.7 for Windows using Visual Studio 2005. I read the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/install-win32.html)  and adapted the paths in the script config.pl according to our internal dependencies.

When I try to build postgresql-8.4.7 I can see that the paths are copied correctly (all of the generated *.vcproj files contain the correct paths) but for e.g. OpenSSL a library named *ssleay32MD.lib* is included, not *ssleay32.lib* which we use internally.

Is this just a question of changing paths and library names and if so which files do I have to edit? I searched the postgresql directory via grep for all possible combinations of the name and fragments of its name, unfortunately to no avail.

I would appreciate a good link or a hint for what I should search.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It might be in the Visual Studio linker settings? Try adding the path of the file you want.

Comment: postgesql uses Perl to preconfigure the settings and run the actual build process from comand line. Every change I make to the Visual Studio settings is overwritten in the build process. I think the paths and names are incorrect before the *.vcproj files are generated. I have never compiled postgesql before so everything is new and I might miss something obivious. Thank you for your answer!